# Android google maps get error Couldn't get connection factory client

Tags: android, google-maps

Android google maps get error **Couldn't get connection factory client**, I have get apikey from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup), this is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.haichal.map;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0IbdGeqd17e6zbTdNfSze2pEt1jJzEEPoOM0jZw"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.haichal.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_app" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And in android project target, I using Google Apis, platform `4.1.2`, Api level `16`.

In my eclipse project no get error(no red ballon), I debug and install success, but when I run apps, maps just get blank grid, not get maps, if I look in log cat I get message error **Couldn't get connection factory client**.

How to solved my problem?

Answer (score 0):

> when i run apps, maps just get blank grid, not get maps

Either your device does not have Internet access (at least to the Google Maps server), or your API key is wrong. Another possibility would be that you lack the `INTERNET` permission, but it appears that you have that already.

> if i look in log cat i get message error Couldn't get connection factory client

That message happens all of the time, even when your app works.